# Why would a CSS snippet work in the HEAD but not in an external Style Sheet?

Tags: html, css, external

I have the following simple piece of HTML:

```
<p class="indexsub">Browse by Name</p>
```

and I have the following piece of css to style it:

```
.indexsub {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #efb03e;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

When I place the css in the HEAD of the web page, it works on all three accounts; size, colour and margins, all applied. If I then take it out to an external style sheet, it completely fails to get applied. Why would that happen?

A few hopefully helpful notes. 1. The rest of the external style sheet works fine. 2. The external style sheet has no conflicting entity called 'indexsub'. 3. I tried placing the css snippet at the very bottom of the external style sheet (so last thing mentioned) in case other settings were somehow countermanding it. This made no difference either. 4. I tried changing the HTML to use a SPAN tag instead of a P tag. Nothing made any difference.

It's important to me to have the css external to the HTML because I need to apply some media-queries to the font size to make it smaller in smaller mobile devices. Thanks.

Comment: did you check if the css file is being loaded into your browser?

Comment: Yes, @mayankTUM, see my note 1 above. The rest of the style sheet works fine.

Comment: Try narrowing down your problem: add another class to your paragraph, define a style for that class - does it get applied? How are you loading your stylesheet? If you make other changes in that stylesheet, do they get applied (i.e. rule out a caching issue)?

Comment: Better check on Chrome inspect element and see if it's being overridden somewhere else.

Comment: The external style sheet is loaded thus: <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, all">
Everything else in the external CSS works fine. Fresh changes to other parts are seen immediately.

Comment: Well, you must be missing _something_... try reproducing an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. on jsfiddle.net, or start ripping things out from your page/stylesheet that aren't relevant to your issue until you find what it is... :-)

Comment: Thanks Heri. I tried that. I'm not familair with Chrome's result format or what it tells me but I do see it mentions p.indexsub - I infer that it's linked up the CSS with this element therefore, but I am no further forward with this.

Comment: can you get me your site link?

Comment: @Amos M. Carpenter - thank you. Your query about caching resonated with me until a eurika (or should I sat "Doh!") moment hit me. I recently opened an account with 'Cloudflare', a CDN. They were caching some elements of the site while I was testing it! Actually still a mystery as to why changes to other parts of the CSS would be reflected instantly but not this 'indexsub' part, but I am too relieved to quibble. Thank you for your input guys. Sorry this would have been one no one could have guessed. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, glad you got to the bottom of it. :-)